# Expressing relationship between Mersenne primes and even perfect numbers as a formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to understand why the Euclid-Euler theorem implies a one-to-one correspondence between Mersenne primes and perfect numbers.

**Theorem 1 (Euclid):**

- *If  $2^{p}−1$  is a Mersenne prime, then  $2^{p−1}⋅(2^{p}−1)$  is perfect.*

**Theorem 2 (Euler):**

- *If $n$ is even and perfect, then there is a Mersenne prime $2^{p}−1$ such that $n = 2^{p−1}(2^{p}−1)$.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem#:%7E:text=one%2Dto%2Done%20relationship%20between%20even%20perfect%20numbers%20and%20Mersenne%20primes%3B%20each%20Mersenne%20prime%20generates%20one%20even%20perfect%20number) and other sources I've come across say that these two theorems together imply a *"one-to-one relationship between even perfect numbers and Mersenne primes; each Mersenne prime generates one even perfect number, and vice versa."*

But it's not intuitive to me why Theorem 2 is the converse of Theorem 1, since we cannot rule out odd perfects. I would prefer to instead verify this using logic rules, but don't know how to express Theorem 2 as a formula.

Assuming the universe of discourse is the natural numbers, if I let

- M(x) = "x is a Mersenne prime"
- P(x) = "x is a perfect number"
- E(x) = "x is even"

...then I can write Theorem 1 as $\forall p(M(2^{p}−1) \rightarrow P(2^{p−1}(2^{p}−1))$.

**But how do I go about expressing Theorem 2 in this way?**

I tried the following

$\forall n[(E(n) \land P(n)) \rightarrow \exists p(M(2^{p}−1) \land n = 2^{p−1}(2^{p}−1))]$

...but I doubt this is correct and I'm not sure where to go from here.

---

EDIT: Someone very helpfully pointed out that the first theorem implies that $2^{p−1}(2^{p}−1)$ is also *even* (in addition to being perfect), since $p$ is prime and therefore the exponent is at least 1.

Here's my new attempt:

Assume the universe is the natural numbers and let $M(w)$, $P(w)$ and $E(w)$ stand for the following statements:

- $M(w)$ – “w is Mersenne prime”
- $P(w)$ – “w is perfect”
- $E(w)$ – “w is even”

Then I can write Theorem 1 as:

$$∀x[M(2^x - 1) \rightarrow \exists y(y = 2^{x-1}(2^x – 1) ∧ P(y) ∧ E(y))]$$

...and Theorem 2 as:

$$∀x[∃y(y = 2^{x-1}(2^x – 1) ∧ P(y) ∧ E(y)) \rightarrow M(2^x - 1)]$$

**But is this equivalent to the statement given above that** "If $n$ is even and perfect, then there is a Mersenne prime $2^{p}−1$ such that $n = 2^{p−1}(2^{p}−1)$"? I'm not sure if I've expressed the consequent properly.

Comment: I am not sure about the formula, but as to why these 2 theorems imply a bijection between Mersenne primes and even perfect numbers is simple. Just consider a function $f$ from the set of Mersenne primes to the even perfect numbers such that $f(2^p-1)=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$. Then Euclid tells you this is injective, and Euler tells you this is surjective.

Comment: There is an easy proof of the converse (that every EVEN perfect number has the mentioned form) in Proofwiki and probably also here on this site. That means that the Mersenne primes correspond $1-1$ with the EVEN perfect numbers. So, we know all EVEN perfect numbers upto millions of digits. Whether ODD perfect numbers exist is unknown, probably there is none.

Comment: Thanks @HackR, I haven't got to functions yet, so I will have to revisit your comment once I have a better grasp of those terms.

Comment: @Peter I have seen the proof, but it goes over my head. But that's ok as I'm just looking to practice sentential logic for now (translating English statements into symbols).